# Minecraft Biome Editor for Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu, minecraft-java-edition-server

I need to change some biomes on my Minecraft server, but I'm on Ubuntu and all the biome editors I can find are for Windows. How can I edit the biomes of my world on Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: Can they run on Wine?

Comment: Is the hosting server command-line only, or do you have graphical access too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/Main_Page), which will work cross-platform, and modify biomes in-game with the biome brush.

Comment: I can't work out how I modify biomes? How do I do it? And, ideally, I'd like to do it on a big scale.

Comment: Don't worry, I found out how to do it. But I don't think it's worked. I selected an area, did //setbiome forest_hills but it's still all snowy.

Comment: @schtocker You'll need to log out and in again to see the change, and changing biome won't remove snow (just change future weather and leaf/grass colour)

Comment: Don't worry, I found that the //thaw command will remove snow. Thanks very much!